# Dynamic Date Lookup

Tags: sql, date, variance

I am close to figuring out how to calculate the price variance of items based on the current month vs the same month in the year prior but I am currently using a static date.

I would ideally want this to be dynamic to whatever the invoice month of the first table is, it looks at matching item transactions in the same month but previous year.

Note, Since I want to use the current month invoice date to drive the line graph, I would need to add it to my first table however, I would prefer to not group by it because I think it may skew my numbers.

Example data is stored here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hAVfDwNw9pNDS9-Nc6U3eafaHb_2pL6f/view?usp=sharing

In the data set above, I would be looking for the results of:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFHnr.png)

My ideal final output would be

Inv Date    Price Variance
June 2020 |  -.011683918
July 2020 |   .046218968

```
WITH cur ([cur_item],[cur_price],[cur_extprice],[cur_volume],[cur_avgprice])

AS

(
SELECT
    inv_item_mst.item AS [cur_item],
    SUM(inv_item_mst.price) AS [cur_price],
    SUM(inv_item_mst.price*inv_item_mst.qty_invoiced) AS [cur_extprice],
    SUM(inv_item_mst.qty_invoiced) AS [cur_volume],
    SUM(inv_item_mst.price*inv_item_mst.qty_invoiced)/NULLIF(SUM(inv_item_mst.qty_invoiced),0) AS [cur_avgprice]

FROM inv_item_mst

LEFT JOIN inv_hdr_mst
    ON inv_item_mst.inv_num=inv_hdr_mst.inv_num
LEFT JOIN customer_mst
    ON inv_hdr_mst.cust_num=customer_mst.cust_num AND inv_hdr_mst.cust_seq=customer_mst.cust_seq

WHERE YEAR(inv_hdr_mst.inv_date)=YEAR(GETDATE()) and MONTH(inv_hdr_mst.inv_date)=MONTH('3/1/2020') 

GROUP BY inv_item_mst.item

)

,

prev ([prev_item],[prev_price],[prev_extprice],[prev_volume],[prev_avgprice])

AS

(
SELECT
    inv_item_mst.item AS [prev_item],
    SUM(inv_item_mst.price) AS [prev_price],
    SUM(inv_item_mst.price*inv_item_mst.qty_invoiced) AS [prev_extprice],
    SUM(inv_item_mst.qty_invoiced) AS [prev_volume],
    SUM(inv_item_mst.price*inv_item_mst.qty_invoiced)/NULLIF(SUM(inv_item_mst.qty_invoiced),0) AS [prev_avgprice]

FROM inv_item_mst

LEFT JOIN inv_hdr_mst
    ON inv_item_mst.inv_num=inv_hdr_mst.inv_num
LEFT JOIN customer_mst
    ON inv_hdr_mst.cust_num=customer_mst.cust_num AND inv_hdr_mst.cust_seq=customer_mst.cust_seq

WHERE YEAR(inv_hdr_mst.inv_date)=YEAR(GETDATE())-1 and MONTH(inv_hdr_mst.inv_date)=MONTH('3/1/2019')
GROUP BY inv_item_mst.item

)

SELECT
cur.cur_item,
CASE
WHEN cur.cur_volume IS NULL
THEN 0
ELSE (cur.cur_avgprice - prev.prev_avgprice)/cur.cur_volume
END AS [price_variance]

from cur

LEFT JOIN prev
    ON cur.cur_item=prev.prev_item
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hi Strawberry - Sorry for not attaching the data set as my query is working for the output standpoint.

I simply was looking to see how to not make the WHERE clauses and get the first table to look at invoices that are June 2020 against June 2019, July 2020 against 2019 etc. based on the Inv Date in the first table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your expected result below?

```
Month  | Price Variance
6      | -0.011683
7      | -0.056540
```

> July 2020 | .046218968

Current is July 2019 and Previous is July 2020. Is this incorrect?

Your database is SQL Server, isn't it?

As a simple way, you can use the CASE expression to calculate data for the current year and the previous year.

```
with cte as (
select
  item,
  format(max(inv_date), 'MM/yyy') as month,
  sum(case when year(inv_date)=year(getdate()) then price end) as cur_price,
  sum(case when year(inv_date)=year(getdate()) then price*qty_invoiced end) as cur_extprice,
  sum(case when year(inv_date)=year(getdate()) then qty_invoiced end) as cur_volume,
  sum(case when year(inv_date)=year(getdate()) then 1.0*price*qty_invoiced end)/sum(case when year(inv_date)=year(getdate()) then qty_invoiced end) as cur_avgprice,
  sum(case when year(inv_date)=year(getdate())-1 then price end) as prev_price,
  sum(case when year(inv_date)=year(getdate())-1 then price*qty_invoiced end) as prev_extprice,
  sum(case when year(inv_date)=year(getdate())-1 then qty_invoiced end) as prev_volume,
  sum(case when year(inv_date)=year(getdate())-1 then 1.0*price*qty_invoiced end)/sum(case when year(inv_date)=year(getdate())-1 then qty_invoiced end) as prev_avgprice
from inv_item_mst
group by item, month(inv_date)
)
select
  month,
  sum((1.0*cur_avgprice - prev_avgprice)/cur_volume) as cur_price_variance,
  sum((1.0*prev_avgprice - cur_avgprice)/prev_volume) as prev_price_variance
from cte
group by month;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=11468da8f0aeab2c8c84508312c9cedf)

Another query with the same result is below:

```
with
cte1 as (
  select
    inv_date,
    year(inv_date) as year,
    month(inv_date) as month,
    item,
    cust,
    qty_invoiced as cur_qty_invoiced,
    price as cur_price,
    cast(NULL as int) as prev_qty_invoiced,
    cast(NULL as int) as prev_price
  from inv_item_mst
  where year(inv_date)=year(getdate())
  union all
  select
    inv_date,
    year(inv_date),
    month(inv_date),
    item,
    cust,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    qty_invoiced,
    price
  from inv_item_mst
  where year(inv_date)=year(getdate())-1
),
cte2 as (
  select
    item,
    month,
    sum(cur_price) as cur_price,
    sum(cur_price*cur_qty_invoiced) as cur_extprice,
    sum(cur_qty_invoiced) as cur_volume,
    sum(1.0*cur_price*cur_qty_invoiced)/sum(cur_qty_invoiced) as cur_avgprice,
    sum(prev_price) as prev_price,
    sum(prev_price*prev_qty_invoiced) as prev_extprice,
    sum(prev_qty_invoiced) as prev_volume,
    sum(1.0*prev_price*prev_qty_invoiced)/sum(prev_qty_invoiced) as prev_avgprice
  from cte1
  group by item, month
)
select
  month,
  sum((1.0*cur_avgprice - prev_avgprice)/cur_volume) as cur_price_variance
from cte2
group by month;
```

1. cte1 has different columns for each year using UNION.
2. cte2 has aggregates grouped by item and month without year.
3. The last query has aggregates for each month.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fed8fdcaef6a8a6850c433ef5ed51f11)